# Advantages of using symfony's filesystem instead of native PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I have found this symfony component [The Filesystem](http://symfony.com/components/Filesystem), but I'm not sure if I should use this component or native PHP. Example with `mkdir`:

```
// With symfony:
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;

$fs = new Filesystem();
$fs->mkdir('/tmp/photos', 0700);

// Native PHP:
mkdir('/tmp/photos', 0700);
```

Same to use `$fs->exists()` instead of `file_exists()`, or `$fs->touch()` instead of `touch()`. Then there is `$fs->copy()` which supports third argument (bool) to toggle overwriting existing file, while native `copy()` will always overwrite destination file.

I'm not using symfony at all, only few of vendors I use do and that is where I found it. I mean, why should I use this component? It seems to me like native functions with extra steps. Your suggestions would help to know if I should use components like that in the future.

Answer (score 6):

1. You do not need to remember the ordering of arguments of PHP built in functions (like, is the [haystack first](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.stristr.php), or [last](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.in-array.php))
2. it's an OOP approach (by definition, easier to grasp)
3. easy to exchange (by the power of `interfaces`) with an engine to work with amazon, dropbox or some other external drive.
4. you define the symfony object once, and then call methods on it, rather than passing around a file pointer, filepath between methods.
5. you do not need to remember, whether you are passing a [resource handle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) which you need to [create/establish](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), or [filename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) as the argument)

That's my point of view.
And **#3 is the biggest strength** in my opinion.

If you are working on a local drive today, and you are doing `file_exists`, it will work. But tomorrow your boss will say "from now on we're CDNing files`. You'll have to go into the code and change all`file_exists`methods with`s3_file_exists`.

Once you are using the Symfony's Class, all you have to do is exchange it with something like: `\Amazon\Custom\Package\FileSystem` and you are good to go!

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me :)

Comment: Hmmm.  #3 is valid assuming you have a need to support multiple file systems but the rest? La la land.  For example, can you point to a single case where php file oriented functions have had their argument order changed?  Didn't think so.  FUD is a bad thing.

Comment: @Cerad Didn't mean the signatures change overtime. I meant inconsistencies between similarly looking methods. For example str_replace($search, $replace, $string) and substr($string, $start, $length). There is no consistent pattern for functions. Each one can have different args ordering.  http://phpsadness.com/sad/9

Comment: Guess I'm in a trolling mood this morning.  With respect to the file system functions, exactly which ones have inconsistent argument ordering which in turn are corrected by the file system component?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 2):

The Filesystem component is a wrapper of some of the PHP [filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Its most important improvement over the plain PHP functions is, in my opinion, the possibility to apply a function recursively on a directory and all its files and subdirectories (`copy()`, `remove()`, `mkdir()`, `chmod()` etc.)

Another important enhancement it provides is the portability. The library takes care of the differences between OSes (directory separator character, some functions that do not exist on Windows etc).